# strcpm() it's not givin me equal

Tags: c, device-driver

I'm trying to get buffer from user and when buffer is equal to 00 B or 00 W then it jumps into the if statement, but for some reason buffer ends up being greater than 0. I have printed out what buffer is and it is 00 B or 00 W when prompted. Why is this?? Am I comparing the wrong thing?

```
ssize_t chess_write(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
    int black;
    int white;

    sprintf(msg, "%s(%zu letters)", buffer, length);
    msg_size = strlen(msg);

    LOG_INFO("In function %s\n", __FUNCTION__);

    LOG_INFO("buffer test in write %s", buffer);    

    black = strcmp(buffer, "00 B");
    white = strcmp(buffer, "00 W");
        if (black == 0)
        {
            LOG_INFO("Chess: Initiate chess as black pieces\n");
        }
        else if (black < 0)
        {
            LOG_INFO("Chess: black is less than 0\n");
        }
        else if (black > 0)
        {
            LOG_INFO("Chess: black is greater than 0\n");
        }
        else if (white == 0)
        {
            LOG_INFO("Chess: Initiate chess as white pieces\n");
        }

    LOG_INFO("Chess: Wrote %zu characters from the user\n", length);
    return length; // return bytes wrote
}
```

The result I get is this

```
[Apr29 18:58] [chess] Module Started
[  +0.000005] [chess] Device class resgistered correctly
[  +0.000077] [chess] Device created correctly
[  +3.632050] [chess] In function chess_open
[  +0.000706] [chess] In function chess_write
[Apr29 19:00] [chess] In function chess_write
[  +0.000003] [chess] buffer test in write 00 B
[  +0.000001] [chess] Chess: black is greater than 0
[  +0.000001] [chess] Chess: Wrote 5 characters from the user
[  +0.001368] [chess] In function chess_read
[  +0.000002] [chess] buffer test in read 00 B
              (5 letters)
[  +0.000001] [chess] Chess: black is greater than 0
[  +0.000002] [chess] Chess: Read 16 characters to the user
[  +0.002089] [chess] In function chess_write
[  +0.000002] [chess] buffer test in write 01
[  +0.000000] [chess] Chess: black is greater than 0
[  +0.000001] [chess] Chess: Wrote 3 characters from the user
[  +0.007073] [chess] In function chess_read
[  +0.000001] [chess] buffer test in read 01
              (3 letters)
[  +0.000001] [chess] Chess: black is greater than 0
[  +0.000001] [chess] Chess: Read 14 characters to the user
```

Ps. I'm handeling LOG_INFO in another file

```
#define _CONFIG_PRINTK(once, level, fmt, ...)                       \
    do{                                     \
        printk##once(KERN_##level "[" MODULE_NAME "] " fmt,     \
                ##__VA_ARGS__);                 \
    } while(0)

#define LOG_INFO(format, ...) _CONFIG_PRINTK(, INFO, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define LOG_WARNING(format, ...) _CONFIG_PRINTK(, WARNING, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define LOG_ERROR(format, ...) _CONFIG_PRINTK(, ERR, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: sprintf() returns a value - you should not ignore it:(

Comment: `"buffer test in write %s"` Change that to `'%s'` and look for trailing characters/whitespace.

Comment: sprintf() returns the number of letters

Comment: Is `length` the number of valid bytes in `buffer` or is `buffer` terminated with a zero byte or both?

Comment: it would improve the question to actually include the program output. And you could try hexdumping the buffer in question to check for non-printable characters

Comment: how do you hexdump? @DavidSchwartz I don't know the answer to that

Comment: @Renato Wonder where that newline after "00 B" came from in the output you just added.

Comment: @Renato Then that's your problem. If you don't know what the parameters mean, there's no way you can get the code to use them correctly.

Comment: @dxiv I'm asking myself the same question

Comment: @Renato The answer is in the code that you did not post. `"01"` for example certainly doesn't have `(3 letters)` as you logged. Guess what the extra character might be.

Comment: `+0.000002] [chess] buffer test in read 00 B
              (5 letters)` There is a '\n' at the end of your string.

Comment: the char array `msg[]` is not defined anywhere in your code!  Is it a global variable?  Is it long enough to contain the complete data, including the trailing NUL byte?

Comment: regarding: `black = strcmp(buffer, "00 B");` and `white = strcmp(buffer, "00 W");`  suggest replacing with:  `black = strncmp(buffer, "00 B", 4);` and `white = strncmp(buffer, "00 W", 4);`